# Function decorators for std::bind in C++0x

Tags: templates, functional-programming, c++11, bind, decorator

I need a function wrapper for std::bind that will be called before the function it's wrapper, passing the arguments along to the wrapped functions.

```
std::function<void (int)> foo = postbind<int>(service, handle);
```

I've so far got down to that

```
std::function<void (int)> foo = postbind(service, handle);
```

How can I remove that template parameter? It seems to come down to the type deduction from the object generation function (postbind) not being intelligent enough.

```
#include <functional>

template<typename T>
void foo(std::function<void (T)> func)
{
}

void handler(int x)
{
}

int main()
{
    foo(handler);
    return 0;
}
```

Says error: no matching function for call to 'foo(void (&)(int))'

Yet, the code sample:

```
template<typename T>
void foo(T t)
{
}

int main()
{
    foo(99);
    return 0;
}
```

This works. Any ideas how to make this work? I need to be able to pass std::bind to it and have the result cast successfully to std::function.

How can I remove the template parameters? Thanks.

---

Q. What is service and this class meant to do?

A. Encapsulate a function wrapper that boost::asio::io_service->posts out of the current thread.

---

Full sourcecode:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>
#include <memory>

class io_service
{
};

typedef std::shared_ptr<io_service> service_ptr;

template <typename Arg1>
class postbind_impl_1
{
public:
    typedef std::function<void (Arg1)> function;

    postbind_impl_1(service_ptr service, function memfunc)
      : service_(service), memfunc_(memfunc)
    {
    }

    void operator()(Arg1 arg1)
    {
        // do stuff using io_service
        memfunc_(arg1);
    }
private:
    service_ptr service_;
    function memfunc_;
};

template <typename Arg1>
postbind_impl_1<Arg1> postbind(service_ptr service, 
        typename postbind_impl_1<Arg1>::function handle)
{
    return postbind_impl_1<Arg1>(service, handle);
}

// ----------------

void handle(int x)
{
    std::cout << x << "\n";
}

int main()
{
    service_ptr service;
    std::function<void (int)> foo = postbind(service, handle);
    foo(110);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What are `service` and `handle`? Can you give an example of the intended usage?

Comment: answered your question above. ATM I pass a function using std::bind to an operation that calls the handle(...) after it finished (i.e handle_connect). If handle_connect is part of an api that runs in a separate thread, then I internally need to have handle_connect just post to do_handle_connect in order to switch threads- ugly. I'd rather have an automatic wrapper in which I pass the io_service along with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To all the naysayers who said this wasn't possible :)

```
/*
 * Defines a function decorator ala Python
 *
 *   void foo(int x, int y);
 *   function<void ()> wrapper(function<void (int)> f);
 *
 *   auto f = decorator(wrapper, bind(foo, 110, _1));
 *   f();
 */

#include <functional>

template <typename Wrapper, typename Functor>
struct decorator_dispatch
{
    Wrapper wrapper;
    Functor functor;

    template <typename... Args>
    auto operator()(Args&&... args)
        -> decltype(wrapper(functor)(std::forward<Args>(args)...))
    {
        return wrapper(functor)(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
    }
};

template <typename Wrapper, typename Functor>
decorator_dispatch<
    Wrapper,
    typename std::decay<Functor>::type
>
decorator(Wrapper&& wrapper, Functor&& functor)
{
    return {wrapper, functor};
}
```

Answer (score 3):

AFAICT argument types of a bind expression are not deducible, so what you want is pretty much impossible.

Answer (score 2):

How do you expect the compiler to know to use `std::function`?  In this code:

```
#include <functional>

template<typename T>
void foo(T func)
{
}

void handler(int x)
{
}

int main()
{
    foo(handler);
    return 0;
}
```

`T` is NOT `std::function<void (int)>`.  It's `void (&)(int)` (like the error message said), a reference to a function, not a functor object.

Deduction of the argument type of the passed function should work, try:

```
#include <functional>

template<typename T>
std::function<void (T)> foo(void (*func)(T))
{
}

void handler(int x)
{
}

int main()
{
    foo(handler);
    return 0;
}
```

Demo: http://ideone.com/NJCMS

If you need to extract argument types from either `std::function` or a plain function pointer, you'll need a helper structure:

```
template<typename>
struct getarg {};

template<typename TArg>
struct getarg<std::function<void (TArg)>> { typedef TArg type; };

template<typename TArg>
struct getarg<void (*)(TArg)> { typedef TArg type; };

template<typename TArg>
struct getarg<void (&)(TArg)> { typedef TArg type; };

template<typename T>
std::function<void (typename getarg<T>::type)> foo(T func)
{
}

void handler(int x)
{
}

int main()
{
    foo(handler);
    return 0;
}
```

Demo: http://ideone.com/jIzl7

With C++0x, you can also match anything that implicitly converts to `std::function`, including return values from `std::bind` and lambdas: http://ideone.com/6pbCC

Comment: The problem with that, is that it doesn't work with std::bind. i.e     std::function<void (int)> foo = postbind(service, std::bind(handle, _1, 9));

Comment: @user: I showed how you can do that using partial specialization and typedef, see update.

Comment: Amazing! Using those proxy objects works great. How can I get std::bind to autoconvert to std::function without needing,        std::function<void (int)> b = postbind(service, std::function<void (int)>(std::bind(handle, _1, 9)));

Comment: i.e the explicit typecast of std::bind to std::function

Comment: @user: Instead of doing that, just add more specializations for whatever type `std::bind` returns (I'm too lazy to check right now).

Comment: I think that's impossible since std::bind returns many different specialisations that can cast to std::function depending on the order of std::placeholderS you provide.

Comment: @user: Then I think you'll need C++0x.  `decltype` and some overloaded functions that match `std::function` (the implicit conversion from `bind`'s return value will be used, as long as there's no all-matching template).  Let me see if I can make that approach work.

Comment: Seems to be impossible. I'm not sure using decltype like that can work. It compiles, but if you change foo(handler) to foo(std::bind(other_handler, _1, 9)); then it fails again.

Comment: @user: Please post a test case on ideone so I can mess around with it.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure what you're trying to achieve, but here's a naive wrapper that stores a list of actions:

```
template <typename R, typename A>
struct wrap
{
  typedef std::function<R(A)> func;

  wrap(func f_) : f(f_) { }

  void prebind(func g) { prebound.push_back(g); }

  R operator()(A arg)
  {
    for (auto it = prebound.cbegin(); it != prebound.cend(); ++it)
    {
      func g = *it;
      g(arg);
    }

    f(arg);
  }
private:
  std::vector<func> prebound;
  func f;
};

wrap<void, int> make_wrap(std::function<void(int)> f)
{
  return wrap<void, int>(f);
}
```

Usage:

```
auto foowrap = make_wrap(foo);

foowrap.prebind(std::function<void(int)>(action1);
foowrap.prebind(std::function<void(int)>(action2);

foowrap(12);  // calls action1(12), action2(12), foo(12)
```

Comment: Now try templating your function make_wrap so you don't have to provide any template arguments and it can deduce the types automatically from foo.

Comment: Hm, wait, I think I just mispasted that -- you should already be able to omit the template parameters from `make_wrap`. Let me edit.

Comment: This is the problem:

    template<typename T>
    std::function<void(T)> make_wrap(std::function<void(T)> f)
    {
      return wrap<void, T>(f);
    }

That template parameterised your function. Now call it without template arguments:

    auto foowrap = make_wrap(foo);

Comment: Yeah, if you want more general signature, you can make `make_wrap` a template. I sort of had this in mind anyway. You should probably make the arguments variadic, too, while you're at it :-)

Comment: except that you cannot. If you try the code above, it won't work :p

Comment: Sorry, the return type of `make_wrap` was wrong, too, should have been `wrap<R,A>`. My own version with variadic templates and perfect forwarding compiles fine!

Comment: Your make_wrap uses void and int. Try changing it to the template parameters and it won't work.

Comment: Agh, crap, I'm getting confused between my local, more general version and the specific one I've listed here. Edited again!

Comment: yep :) so a very specific make_wrap isn't too useful. The point here is to have a generic function that can deduce it's own type.